# Comment/Uncomment multiple lines in Snowflake (German keyboard)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

how can I comment or uncomment multiple lines in Snowflake?

The docs says  `CTRL` + `/` but because I got a german keyboard the / is a capital 7. And `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `7` is not working either.

Is there any way to comment and uncomment multiples lines in Snowflake if you dont use an US-Keyboardlayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any keyboard shortcuts. You can enclose the lines with /* and */

```
/*
This is a comment

and another comment.
this one too.
*/

This is NOT a comment.
```

Answer (score -1):

For Mac User: Select the multi-line and press 'command'& '/' keys

Comment: The issue is that there isn't plain "/" key on the german keyboard. You need to type shift+7 to get it. The combination of cmd+shift+7 doesn't work though.